Debug view isn't working when I use Google Analytics API in Postman
I want to query google analytic's endpoint to store data from my desktop app, at this moment I'm only using Postman to test, now It works but I've to wait 48 hours to see my requests in the dashboard. I hear that I can use debugview to see the events fired in a period of 30 minutes, but it is empty.
This is the endpoint I'm querying
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=<measurement>&api_secret=<secret>
{
    "client_id": "jorge_mostro_1",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "test_measurement",
            "params": {
                "param1": "1234",
                "param2":"5670"
            }
        }
    ]
}

